# How to prevent dragging(moving) element outside droppable div? (Vanila JS only)

Tags: javascript

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  if (ev.target.id === "div1") {
    console.log("Running Stop Drop");
    document.getElementById("img1").setAttribute("draggable", false);
  }
}



  // shuffle

  function shuffle() {
    var container = document.getElementById("images");
    var elementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(container.getElementsByClassName('grid-item'));
    elementsArray.forEach(function (element) {
      container.removeChild(element);
    })
    shuffleArray(elementsArray);
    elementsArray.forEach(function (element) {
      container.appendChild(element);
    })
  }

  function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }
```

```css
body {
  background:#6b6b69;
  color:white;
}

.info {
  position:relative;
  font-family:Arial;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:5px;
  font-size:15px;
}

#title {
  font-size:20px;
}

#rest2 {
  font-size:13px;
}

#text div {
  position:relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

#text {
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  width: 0%;
  
 
}

#images { display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  width: 0%
}

img {
  border: #6b6b69 2px solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}


#drag4,
#drag5,
#drag6,
#drag7,
#drag8,
#drag9,
#drag10,
#drag11,
#drag12 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  display: inline-block;
}

#drag4 {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, orange, orange, yellow);
}

#drag5 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange);
}

#drag6 {
  background: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}

#drag7 {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, red, orange);
}

#drag8 {
  background:yellow;
}

#drag9 {
  background: linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
}

#drag10 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, yellow);
}

#drag11 {
  background: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}

#drag12 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red,orange);
}
.puzzle{display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="info">
    <div id="title">PUZZLE</div>
    <div id="rest">Drag and drop the colored pieces on the puzzle below. (better images are on their way) </div>
    <div id="rest2">You can put multiple pieces in the same area but you can't interchange them, only the last one you
      put will be accessible.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="puzzle">
    <div style="float:left;" id="images">
    
      <img class="grid-item" id="img1" src="img/puzz1.jpg" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="grid-item" id="img2" src="img/puzz2.jpg" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="grid-item" id="img3" src="img/puzz3.jpg" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="grid-item" id="img4" src="img/puzz4.jpg" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">


    </div>


    <div style="float: right" id="text">
      <div class="grid-item2" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      <div class="grid-item2" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      <div class="grid-item2" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      <div class="grid-item2" id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    </div>
  </div><br><br>
  <button onclick="shuffle()">
    START
  </button>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Congratulations if you finished!<p>
  </div>
  <script src="dragdrop3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am building kind of a puzzle game with a drag and drop elements, I have 4 draggable images on the left and 4 empty divs on the right, similar drag and drop event to this w3Shchool example I posted here.

My question is how to prevent image to leave div2 on the right once it is dropped inside? I want it to be permanent, not draggable just locked once is dropped.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1, #div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not create a different drop handler for the right side that disables dragging for any elements dropped on it? Using the same handler for both complicates things.

Comment: That's precisely what I trying to achieve, but I don't know the code how to disable that? Can you please post some simple examples of it? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very crude way of doing it (IMO), but it works.

Explanation: `ondrop` complete I make the `img` element un-dropable.

`document.getElementById("drag1").setAttribute("draggable", false);`

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

  if(ev.target.id === "div2"){
      console.log("Running Stop Drop");
      document.getElementById("drag1").setAttribute("draggable", false);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1, #div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One easy improvement here is to make `drop` take a second argument `permanent` that if true calls the `setAttribute` to disable draggable. Then it's not bound to any particular name.

Comment: Yes, But that would change the OP's code structure. That would complicate the already confusing thing for him.

Comment: That's a fair observation.

Comment: That works, but only for 1 of my 4 images. I will post now my own code so you can look. Thanks, guys for the answers, this is my first question ever on Stack :)

Comment: Don't worry about it. Make some an example of your code online, You can write it in the question or some ppl also write on jsfiddle or codepen. Codesandbox is also popular for npm packages related codebase.

Comment: Ok. the condition that you use is for `div1`. So, It only works for div1. You need to setup conditions like these `if (ev.target.id === "div1") {` for all the divs

Comment: Thanks, Ahmad, it is encouraging when someone helped you, I need to get used to this commenting and posting :) I posted my own code up on top the page, so you can look if you got time.

Comment: I did look at your code that's why I told you that condition for every div solution. Also remember you shouldn't usually post all of your code in the question. Only the part or similar example that relates to your question.

Comment: Yes, but when I drag any of my images from left div to right div, it became locked on the left div as well if you know what I mean. I want to be draggable on the left all the time, but when any of them is dragged and dropped in the right div, they became locked in that div, and then I put the rest of the images as well in empty divs and lock them all in right. I hope I did not confuse you. Here is a similar example https://codepen.io/tobiasdev/pen/bedRmL      All I want is to remain locked on the right and movable on the left

Comment: Ok. Here is what you need to do. First understand why my example in the awnser is working. Then try to apply same logic to your code, Then if it isn't working ask a question like You tried to make thing A to thing B but thing A isn't not becoming thing B.

Comment: Sorry, It's gonna feel little harsh, But there is a difference b/w asking ppl to solve a problem for me vs can some tell why this thing that should be doing this cause I wrote this code but it's doing that not this. It'll serve you better with asking ppl for help.

Comment: Don't apologize Ahmad, you are totally realistic :) I will try to apply some more logic to it, yesterday I was really tired, and if I run in some bigger problem I will get you posted . Thanks